# PHP setcookie strange behaviour in Android

Tags: php, android, cookies

I´ve a web page that sets a cookie every time the users log in.
I set the cookie this way:

```
$expire = time() + $seconds;
$manager->setCookie('name', 'value' , 'value' ,$expire);
```

Everything works fine at every device and browser, but when running the page in android internet browser (android version 4.4.2) it looks like the cookie is not being stored in the browser, unless $seconds is higher than 6100.

So, if i set `$expire = time() + 6000`, the cookie seems not to be stored; but if I set `$expire = time() + 6100` everything works.

Does anybody know why this strange issue happens?

Comment: Did you give us the exact code you used to set a cookie? `$manager->setCookie('name', 'value' , 'value' ,$expire);` Why do you have 'value' twice?

Comment: it was only an example, but the real values of setCookie params don´t change the behaviour of the script, but $expire does

Comment: Does this android device keep this cookie for longer than 100 seconds? Just thinking if it could be a time issue in a way that the time set is already expired on the device. Just a thought though...

Comment: The browser time and the server time must differ.